# Size of my input field type number cant be changed

Tags: html, forms

I have a HTML form in which i have some input fields, some set to `type="text"` and some others to `type="number"`.

In my `type="text"` fields i can use this parameter `size="3"` but in my `type="number"` this parameter just get ignored, my input field size is so long. And people need to be able to only type 3 numbers in these fields. So an input field which is the size of like 20 chars is not very appealing.

And i can't just change it back to text since, well, it can only be numbers.

So is there some way i can change the sizeof the `type="number"` ?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Thanks guys for the min,max but that only solves the maxlength problem. Is there a way for the size one as well?

Thanks anyway!

EDIT: Rephrased my question

Comment: This question has already been asked several times on Stack Overflow. Use the `max` attribute.

Comment: Just use 999 as the max value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `min` and `max` attributes.

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="999" step="1" />
```

Comment: Right, totally forgot about those.. Also that solves only the maxlength problem. Thanks for that. But is there also a way to change the size?

Comment: @user2966317 sure, CSS.

Comment: Thanks, making a class and use px for the width fixed my problem.

Comment: Setting `max` styles the input box to the "right" size in several browsers (e.g. based on Webkit), but not in Firefox (including v31). So you may have had to use CSS because you are on a browser that separates the HTML tag from its styling. It seems a more portable way is to rely on CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Use [min](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-min) and [max](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-max) attributes .
Refer http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-input-element.html for all possible attributes

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify a range of value

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="999" />
```

which will only accept inputs between 0 and 999.